# Vector equation of a circle

Tags: vector-analysis

Recently I came across the vector equation of a circle as
$$r(t)=a+b \cos(t) +c \sin(t)$$
I want to prove it but I am unable to proceed . The only thing I feel is that $a$ which is actually $(a_x,a_y,a_z)$ is the center. I am not sure if I am correct.  Please help me with the proof.

Comment: Unless $\|b\|=\|c\|$ and $b \perp c$, this is not a circle.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but is there some proof like deriving the vector equation for a line. And why that vector a is centre of circle

Comment: First things first: what definition of a circle are you familiar with?

Comment: I am familiar with all the definitions except the vector one. Please help.

Comment: Assuming $\vec b,\vec c$ are orthogonal unit vectors, what is $|\vec r-\vec a|$?

Comment: That should be the radius of the circle

Comment: But what about the other terms, I am not getting your point , Sorry, please provide a little more insight

Comment: $|\vec r-\vec a|=|\hat b\cos t+\hat c\sin t|=\sqrt{|\hat b\cos t|^2+|\hat c\sin t|^2}=1$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri You've missed a couple of squares / square roots there, and an assumption that $\|b\|=\|c\|=1$. Furthermore, this doesn't prove this is an equation of a circle, it only proves that it is a subset of a sphere centered at $a$.

Comment: @lisyarus This is of course not a complete answer, it is meant to be a starting point. I'm sure the assumption that $|\vec b|=1$ doesn't materially change the pattern of the proof.

Comment: How are you saying that b and c values are equal to 1 @Shubham Johri, you are just taking a special case . A proof requires something in general.

Comment: @lisyarus can you provide some vectorial proof for this circle equation

Comment: Clearly the information $|\vec b|=|\vec c|,\vec b\perp\vec c=0$ is missing from your question, which is necessary for the given equation to represent a circle. In case $|\vec b|\ne1$ but assuming $|\vec b|=|\vec c|$, you will get $|\vec r-\vec a|=|\vec b|$ which is fine since all we want to show is that the distance of $\vec r$ from $\vec a$ is fixed. The pattern of proof is similar.

Comment: Ok @Shubham Johri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get rid of the first term $a$ which adds only a "final" translation.

The result is that $r=b \cos(t) +c \sin(t)$ where $b,c$ are 3D vectors is a parametric equation of an **ellipse** situated evidently in the vector plane (P) defined by $b$ and $c$.

Why is it an ellipse ?

Let us consider the 2D problem in plane (P) with 2D notations. It means that vectors $B$ and $C$ being given in this 2D plane, and we are looking for the nature of the curve described by

$$R=B \cos(t) + C \sin(t)\tag{2}$$

with coordinates et $R=(x,y)$, $B=(B_x,B_y)$ and $C=(C_x,C_y)$

(2) is equivalent to the following system of equations :

$$\begin{cases}x&=&B_x \cos(t)+C_x\sin(t)\\y&=&B_y \cos(t)+C_y\sin(t)\end{cases} \ \ \iff \ \ \begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}B_x&C_x\\B_y&C_y\end{pmatrix}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t)\\ \sin(t)\end{pmatrix}}_{\text{unit circle}}\tag{3}$$

therefore an ellipse as the affine image of the unit circle.

Remark : we will get a circle is the above $2 \times 2$ matrix is the matrix of a similitude, hopefully composed with a symmetry, which means that the columns of the matrix should be orthogonal with the same length.

Coming back to 3D, the last sentence means that we get a circle iff $b \perp c$ **and** $\|b\|=\|c\|$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  the best thing is I have understood everything you said☺️

Comment: Thanks. Happy it was understandable.